# Send a message to a handler periodically

Tags: android

In the main activity, I have a handler running on a separate thread. I need to send a message to that handler periodically without blocking the ui main thread..How would I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by handler 'running' in a separate thread? Do you want to send messages to another thread? Please, give more details and show the related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a generic Java answer, check out timers: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

For an Android-specific answer, check out AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html